# Use NDK(C code) in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In my android application, I use NDK for a part of the app, this is the C code of the implement ion:

```
#include <jni.h>

#define DEFAULT_NUM 10
#define LEN 10
int fixedNum
double defaultDoubleArray[LEN];
double fixedDoubleArray[LEN];
 void JNICALL Java_com_app_Constant_init (JNIEnv *, jclass, jfloat)
 {
        setArray(defaultDoubleArray,DEFAULT_NUM);
        fixedNum=DEFAULT_NUM*jfloat;
        setArray(fixedDoubleArray,fixedNum);
 }


 jdoubleArray JNICALL Java_com_app_Constant_getArray(JNIEnv *, jclass, jboolean useDefault)
 {
    jdoubleArray result = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env, LEN);
    (*env)->SetDoubleArrayRegion(env, result, 0, LEN, useDefault?defaultDoubleArray:fixedDoubleArray);
    return result;
 }

 jint JNICALL Java_com_app_Constant_getNum (JNIEnv *, jclass, jboolean useDefault)
 {
    return useDefault?DEFAULT_NUM:fixedNum;
 }


void setArray(conat int* ary,int num){
    for(i=0;i<LEN;i++){
        ary[i]=...... // fill value

}
```

}

But it does not work when I use `ndk-build` to compile it, and it seems that there are not only the syntax problem but also the implement ion.

I am not familiar with C or C++, I hope someone can tell me what's wrong?

---

build log:

```
D:\workspace\application\jni>ndk-build
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : Constant <= Constant.c
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:7:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'double'
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:16:2: error: parameter name omitted
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:16:2: error: parameter name omitted
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c: In function 'Java_com.app.Constant_getArray':
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:21:2: error: parameter name omitted
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:21:2: error: parameter name omitted
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:23:26: error: 'env' undeclared (first use in this function)
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:23:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:24:62: error: 'defaultDoubleArray' undeclared (first use in this function)
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:24:80: error: 'fixedDoubleArray' undeclared (first use in this function)
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c: In function 'Java_com.app.Constant_getTileSize':
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:28:2: error: parameter name omitted
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:28:2: error: parameter name omitted
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:30:36: error: 'fixedNum' undeclared (first use in this function)
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c: In function 'setArray':
D:/workspace/application//jni/Constant/Constant.c:35:6: error: 'i' undeclared (first use in this function)
make.exe: *** [D:/workspace/application//obj/local/armeabi/objs/t/Constant/t.o] Error 1
```

Comment: _"it does not work"_ is not a good problem description. _Exactly_ which errors do you get?

Comment: I update the question and upload the errors.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that you're missing something that it expected to find. In this case it's a semicolon after `findNum`. There may be other errors in your code, so you'll have to fix each once and go through the remaining compiler errors until you've fixed all of them.

Comment: That's right, thank you, after fix the `semicolon` problem, the new error seems easy to understand, I made it work now. :)